# ionic scroll stops working after some using

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm developing a ionic application.now i have this issue of ionic scrolling not working after a while. when running the app in a device the scrolling is working as it should.but after sometime scrolling stops working in other forms in my application. It's not freezing the app because i can still enter input data into fields in my form eventhough the scroll is not working.problem is i cannot view the fields in the bottom because the scroll is not working. Anyone has a solution for this?

I'll post a html form here.all other forms are done like this

```
<ion-view title="rrrr">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-content class="has-header" scroll="true" padding="true">

        <ion-list>

            <!-- pass in the variable if our form is valid or invalid -->
            <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>

                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">
                    <label><h4><b>Beneficiary Name*</b></h4></label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="item-input-wrapper" ng-model="user.name" ng-maxlength="50"  required>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine " class="help-block"><font color="red">You name is required.</font></p>

                        </div>

                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.accNo.$invalid && !userForm.accNo.$pristine }">
                    <label><h4><b>Beneficiary Account Number*</b></h4></label>
                    <input type="number" name="accNo" class="item-input-wrapper" ng-model="user.accNo"  ng-maxlength="10"   required>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine " class="help-block"><font color="red">Account number is required</font></p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.accNo.$error.maxlength" class="help-block"><font color="red">Account number cannot exceed 10 digits.</font></p>
                        </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label><h4><b>Bank Name*</b></h4></label>
                    <select style="margin: auto; width:100%; height=35px;" id="user.bank" ng-model="user.bank" ng-options="bank.bank for bank in banks" >
                        <option id="default" value="" selected="selected">--Select Bank--</option>

                    </select>

                </div>


                <label><h4><b>Bank Code*</b></h4></label>
                <input type="text" name="bcode" class="item-input-wrapper" ng-model="user.bankCode"  required>

                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.brname.$invalid && !userForm.brname.$pristine }">

                        <label><h4><b>Branch Name*</b></h4></label>
                        <input type="text" name="brname" class="item-input-wrapper" ng-model="user.bankBranch"  required>
                            <p ng-show="userForm.brname.$invalid && !userForm.brname.$pristine " class="help-block"><font color="red">Branch Name is required</font></p>
                            </div>


                    <div class="col"style="text-align: center">
                        <button align="left"class="button button-block button-reset"style="display: inline-block;width:100px;text-align:center "
                            type="reset"
                            ng-click="reset()"padding-top="true">Reset</button>


                        <button class="button button-block button-positive"  style="display: inline-block;width:100px "
                            ng-click="submit(user)"padding-top="true">Submit</button>
                    </div>



                    </form>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

angularjs for this

```
$scope.data = {
    origin: { account : ''},
    beneAcc: '',
    narration: '',
    beneName: '',
    beneBank: {account : ''},
    transtype: '',
    beneBranch: '',
    password: '',
    amount: ''
};

$scope.orig = angular.copy($scope.data);
$scope.accountsArr = [];

for(k=0;k<$rootScope.rootScopeUserAccounts.length;k++){
    var accountObject  = $rootScope.rootScopeUserAccounts[k];
    $scope.accountsArr.push({ account: accountObject.userAccountNumber });
}

//gaveen
$scope.listOne = [{"id":"1","name":"Internal"},{"id":"2","name":"SLIPS"},{"id":"3","name":"CEFT"}]
$scope.listTwo = [{"id":"1","name":"Seylan Bank"},{"id":"2","name":"Sampath Bank"},{"id":"3","name":"BOC"}]
$scope.listThree = [{"id":"1","name":"Colombo 01"},{"id":"2","name":"Colombo 02"},{"id":"3","name":"Colombo 03"}]

// $scope.data.transtype = $scope.listOne[0].name;

$scope.hideFields = function() {
    if($scope.data.transtype.name == "Internal") {
        $scope.disableFields = true;
        $scope.typeFlag= false;
    }
    else{
        $scope.disableFields = false;
        $scope.typeFlag= true;
    }
};

$scope.bank = [
    { bank : 'Sampath Bank'},
    {bank : 'BOC'},
];

$scope.thirdPartySubmit = function(selectData) {
    window.alert(selectData.amount);
    //
    console.log("came here!");

    //add decimals to whole numbers.
    if(selectData.amount % 1 == 0){
        var transferAmount = parseFloat(selectData.amount).toFixed(2);
        window.alert(transferAmount);
    }

    //create json dictionary.
    var data = {
        "transferedAmount" : selectData.amount,
        "beneficiaryAccountNumber" : selectData.beneAcc,
        "beneficiaryType" : "THIRD_PARTY",
        "beneficiaryBankName" : selectData.beneBank.name,
        "beneficiaryName" : selectData.beneName,
        "branchName" : selectData.beneBranch.name,
        "userAccountNumber" : selectData.origin.account,
        "narration" : selectData.narration,
        "userName" : "retail123",
        "thirdPartyFundTransferType" : selectData.transtype.name
     };
     window.alert(data);
     $scope.jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

     window.alert($scope.jsonData);

     //POST data
     $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: ApplicationSettings.http_server + 'account service/fund-transfer/save',
                                     data: $scope.jsonData
     })
     .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         console.log("Success");
         window.alert("Transaction success!");
         $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.orig);
         $scope.thirdPartyForm.$setPristine();
     })
     .error(function(data,status, headers, config) {
         // execute this code on error
         window.alert("error");
         window.alert(status);
         //refreshTextFields.refresh(selectData);
         $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.orig);
         $scope.thirdPartyForm.$setPristine();
         console.error('ERR', err);
     });
}
//end of function

$scope.reset = function () {
    $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.orig);
    $scope.thirdPartyForm.$setPristine();
};
}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your ionic-framework version?

I had the same problem on Samsung S3 with ionic version 1.0.0-beta9.

According to this issue: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1433

version greater then 1.0.0-beta12 should work fine with scrolling.